# root folder access

Tags: permissions

When I open my computer folder (the one below network and above optical drive if that helps) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I find a button up top next to the < and > and before the home button. When I open it I find all my folders. One of these is titled "root" and has an x in the bottom right of the folder icon. The size is indicated by a "?" mark and I am not permitted to open it. I don't like not having access to things on my own computer and not knowing the size of it. When watching a video for Ubuntu for Newbies, I noticed that the operator in the video did't have the "x" on his folder. Is this normal to be blocked from my own root folder? Can I unlock it some how? Should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **root** folder is the home folder for the **root** user and yes, you are not supposed to open it.  Only the **root** user is.

If you run `nautilus` with root rights though or if you use use a root terminal, you will be able to access it normally.  There's nothing of interest in there though and you shouldn't change anything in that folder unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I guess that lever will be titled "B".